# How to add custom user avatar in wordpress

Tags: functions, avatar

I use below code for adding media uploader to user edit profile page WP.
Now, how to use in for show in single.php page? I have an error in single page:

```
<img src="<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mihansanat/wp-content/themes/mihansanat/single.php</b> on line <b>64</b><br />
Array">
```

**Uploader.js**

```
 /**
 * Theme Options Scripts
 */

jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    /* WP Media Uploader */
    var _shr_media = true;
    var _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;

    jQuery( '.shr-image' ).click( function() {

        var button = jQuery( this ),
                textbox_id = jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-id' ),
                image_id = jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-src' ),
                _shr_media = true;

        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function( props, attachment ) {

            if ( _shr_media && ( attachment.type === 'image' ) ) {
                if ( image_id.indexOf( "," ) !== -1 ) {
                    image_id = image_id.split( "," );
                    $image_ids = '';
                    jQuery.each( image_id, function( key, value ) {
                        if ( $image_ids )
                            $image_ids = $image_ids + ',#' + value;
                        else
                            $image_ids = '#' + value;
                    } );

                    var current_element = jQuery( $image_ids );
                } else {
                    var current_element = jQuery( '#' + image_id );
                }

                jQuery( '#' + textbox_id ).val( attachment.id );
                                console.log(textbox_id)
                current_element.attr( 'src', attachment.url ).show();
            } else {
                alert( 'Please select a valid image file' );
                return false;
            }
        }

        wp.media.editor.open( button );
        return false;
    } );

} );
```

**function.php**

```
function shr_add_admin_scripts(){

    wp_enqueue_media();
    wp_enqueue_script('shr-uploader', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/uploader.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'shr_add_admin_scripts');
function shr_extra_profile_fields( $user ) {

    $profile_pic = ($user!=='add-new-user') ? get_user_meta($user->ID, 'shr_pic', true): false;

    if( !empty($profile_pic) ){
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $profile_pic, 'thumbnail' );

    } ?>

    <table class="form-table fh-profile-upload-options">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="image"><?php _e('Main Profile Image', 'shr') ?></label>
            </th>

            <td>
                <input type="button" data-id="shr_image_id" data-src="shr-img" class="button shr-image" name="shr_image" id="shr-image" value="Upload" />
                <input type="hidden" class="button" name="shr_image_id" id="shr_image_id" value="<?php echo !empty($profile_pic) ? $profile_pic : ''; ?>" />
                <img id="shr-img" src="<?php echo !empty($profile_pic) ? $image[0] : ''; ?>" style="<?php echo  empty($profile_pic) ? 'display:none;' :'' ?> max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><?php

}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'shr_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'shr_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'user_new_form', 'shr_extra_profile_fields' );
function shr_profile_update($user_id){

    if( current_user_can('edit_users') ){
        $profile_pic = empty($_POST['shr_image_id']) ? '' : $_POST['shr_image_id'];
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'shr_pic', $profile_pic);
    }

}
add_action('profile_update', 'shr_profile_update');
add_action('user_register', 'shr_profile_update');
```

**single.php**

```
  <?php
    $author_id=get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $user_meta=get_user_meta( $author_id,  'shr_pic', true);
    $image  =   wp_get_attachment_image_src($user_meta, 'thumbnail');
  ?>
   <img src="<?php echo $image ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` returns an array. You want `wp_get_attachment_image_url()`.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_url($user_meta, 'thumbnail');
```